# Questions about proof of intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I was reading the proof of intermediate value theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#Proof
But I cannot understand the last sentence of the statement below.

> Define $S = \lbrace x \in [a, b] \; | \; f(x) \leq u \rbrace$ and $c$ as the supremum of $S$. Choose some $\epsilon$. By continuity, there exists $\delta$ such that $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$. By the properties of the supremum, we can chose some $a^*$ from $(c - \delta, c]$ such that $a^* \in S$.

Suppose that the function looks like below and we choose $u$ as indicated on the axis. The set $S$ is colored in blue. In this case, $c$ is an isolated point and thus, we cannot guarantee the existence of $a^*$ within $\delta$-neighborhood of $c$.

[image]

Clearly I have misunderstood about something, but where did I get wrong?

**Edit**: In the above case, $a^* = c$, but now I'm wondering how we can guarantee that $c = \sup S \in S$.

Comment: It says you can pick an intersection so that the construction works due to continuity, it does not say that there do not exist other intersections that fail to work

Comment: @Renard Could you explain a bit more about "intersection"? I have read the proof again but didn't recognize any mention of intersection.

Comment: The Wikipedia article says $(c - \delta, c]$, not $(c - \delta, c)$.

Comment: @EricM.Schmidt Oh my, I can't believe I didn't recognize that. Something must've slipped off, thank you :)

Comment: @Dimen If your problem has been resolved, consider posting an answer yourself in the answers section. That will help take this question off the unanswered list. On SE sites it is not proper to edit the title to say "Solved".